# "Teacher" Badge

Tags: feature-request

I see that you have a teacher badge, but it would be nice if there was a signature or something that could be added if one is actually a teacher offline.  Aside from my experience with my own child, I have the experience of ten years in the classroom and all the exposure to the many different types of children that come with it.  I would like to know where other posters are coming from in terms of their real life experience as well.  Something indicating #children, ages of children and any other related experience would be helpful to see on posts.

I thought the teacher badge was something more akin to this until I registered and learned more about what the badges really were.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Badges don't indicate any real-life status of the user, professional or otherwise. The `teacher` badge is used by all sites in the StackExchange network, and it's an insignificant coincidence that its meaning overlaps here on Parenting.

The badges are meant a motivation to contribute, and as a symbol of thanks for past contributions and achievements. They indicate how active and appreciated a user is.

You can use the biographical description in your profile to mention anything you feel is relevant to your user profile -- which you have done.

Comment: I guess I wish there was a quicker view of such information on posts. I'm interested to know where some of the posters get their wonderful insight. Thanks though. I see others have asked similar questions.